# Automate Deployments with Git, Bitbucket and PHP

Tags: php, git, deployment, bitbucket

I'm in the process of trying to set up automatic deployments when I make a git push to my bitbucket repository.  I have a php deploy script that I leveraged from [this blog](http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/) but when the script runs it is logging that it's only updating from a previous commit.

Here is an example.  Let say I log into my server and type git pull.  The server will update with the latest changes and lets say the hash for that commit was 001.  However if I make several commits lets call them 002, 003, and 004 my script should run every time assuming I pushed those changes to bitbucket after every commit.  The script runs but every time it will keep the changes from 001.  Only when I log into my server and type git pull, will the server update to 004. Do you know what would cause this?

```
// Make sure we're in the right directory
exec('cd '.$this->_directory, $output);
$this->log('Changing working directory... '.implode(' ', $output));

// Discard any changes to tracked files since our last deploy
exec('git reset --hard HEAD', $output);
$this->log('Reseting repository... '.implode(' ', $output));

// Update the local repository
exec('git pull '.$this->_remote.' '.$this->_branch, $output);
$this->log('Pulling in changes... '.implode(' ', $output));

// Secure the .git directory
exec('chmod -R og-rx .git');
$this->log('Securing .git directory... ');

if (is_callable($this->post_deploy))
{
 call_user_func($this->post_deploy, $this->_data);
}

$this->log('Deployment successful.');
```

Comment: Do you have submodules as well? If so, don't forget `git submodule update`.

Comment: I honestly don't know what a submodule is.  I've just started using bitbucket and git.

Comment: A submodule is a repository in your repository which points to a tag. I suggest to not use it when possible. This might be the case if you have multiple internal applications using the same plugins/libraries. They invented composer for this ;)

Comment: If you make use of an external library that has a git repo, you can set up a _submodule_, which points to a particular commit inside that remote repo. If you update a submodule in your working repo (e.g. you upgrade the library to a later version) then you need to issue the above command on your remote repo to bring the submodule up to date with its current commit. The git manual will explain more, and will walk you through an example so it makes more sense `:)`.

Answer (score 5):

What I would recommend is to release not based on latest version in your master, but a latest tag.

`/home/my-user/my-application/1.0.12/www`
`/home/my-user/my-application/1.0.13/www`

etc. This provides rollback functionality. You could make a PHP script that connects to your server over SSH and makes a new clone based on that tag. If you use Composer, you can use this to execute commands. If not, you can do it with a makefile.

Edit: I have forgot to mention how you actually link it.

You have a symlink
`/home/my-user/my-application/www -> /home/my-user/my-application/1.0.12/www`

When your entire deployment script is finished without errors, you switch the symlink to:
`/home/my-user/my-application/www -> /home/my-user/my-application/1.0.13/www`

Your application is now live without downtime.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and efficient approach is to use *bitbucket pipelines*, you can create a YAML script to compile your dependences and push the code to a server on each commit, automatimagicaly or manually.

Here is an example of a Bitbucket Pipelines YAML script:

```
image: php:7.1.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
       caches:
         - composer
       script:
         - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
         - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
         - composer install
    - step:
       deployment: staging
       name: Deploy to Staging Server
       script:
         - apt-get update
         - apt-get -qq install rsync 
         - echo "Upload Project files..."
         - rsync -avH * -e "ssh" root@$IP_SERVER:/var/www/html/
```

This script installs the Composer dependencies inside a Docker instance and pushes the projects files to server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is file permissions.

I was following the same link to that blogpost. I found that the 'www-data' user that is used by php and nginx processes, does not have write permissions to your repository code. It cannot even use git.

For verifying this try doing a 'git pull' on the server as 'www-user'. You can switch to it by 'sudo su www-data'. You will find that it does not even recognize that as a valid git repo and is unable to run your 'deploy.php' script without errors.

You need to set proper permissions to your repository so that www-data can access it.

Or you change the whole approach. Follow this post http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto which I feel is a much better method than the above. I ended up using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a `post-update` hook in the remote you push to.

In the default case git will not checkout any data you push to a remote. That's why the default git configuration refuses to push to the *checked out branch* as the checked out files aren't up-to-date with HEAD anymore, when you push to the checkout-out branch.

When the remote receives a push to a branch you can react on that in the `post-update` hook, though. To see what happens you should first start with some logging:

```
echo "post update `date`: $*" >> /home/ingo/test/githooks.out
```

When I push to the branch new, for example I get the line

```
post update Mi 24. Jun 13:01:14 CEST 2015: refs/heads/new
```

, where `$*` contains the branches I pushed to.

With this you can write simply write a script to checkout that branch. I prefer checking out to detached heads, as its much simpler to combine work from several module repositories (no submodules) into a deployed version. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939511/how-to-automate-deployment-of-source-compiled-code-excluding-git-history-to/30940591#30940591) to the source code deployment on how to checkout code outside of the git repository and work with that.

For example you could do

```
for b in $*
do B=`basename $b`
if [ "$B" = "publish" ] # react on changes to the publish branch
then git --work-tree "PATH TO THE PUBLISHED WORK TREE" checkout publish
do_some_extra_work # to change permissions or inform your team leader
fi done
```

Of course you can do the checkout step too, that is done on a pull

```
if [ "`cat HEAD`" = "ref: refs/heads/master" ]
# only do that checkout if the repository is in a sane state
then git merge new # I assume you push to new
fi
```

The cool thing is that you will see the output of your hook on the remote in the terminal where you executed the push:

```
# git push remote master:new
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 296 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Updating f81ba5b..a99a710
remote: Fast-forward
remote:  a.txt | 2 ++
remote:  1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
To ../remote
    db48da1..a99a710  master -> new
```