# How to automate deployment of source & compiled code (excluding git history) to third-party developers?

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I'm going to setup some tools/techiques/environments so that when I need to provide the source code for third-party developers, I do it without git history with some sensitive code already compiled and stripped. So I want to automate this process, so that I always provide the latest version of it without the pain of doing all necessary steps by hands everytime.
I use bitbucket and git.

**How can my goals be accomplished using bitbucket and git? Do I need some other tools?**

P.S. Feel free to edit the question if it doesn't state clear the idea. I hope this questions is not too broad and doesn't fall under restrictions

Comment: Yeah, there's a close reason specifically for recommendations.  I'd suggest you [edit] to ask *how* your goals can be accomplished using bitbucket and git.

Comment: Google for "continuous integration". Start with Atlassian Stash, which is compatible with Bitbucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to write some `post-commit` hook. But that might be too fine grained for you. Just write the automatic steps to `.git/hooks/post-commit` and make that executable. You can

```
git --work-tree PATH_FOR_THIRD_PARTY checkout HEAD -- PUBLIC_FILES
```

to update the PUBLIC_FILES for your third-party developers in PATH_FOR_THIRD_PARTY, where I assume you publish the data for the third-party developers.

Then to update the compiled results you shoud write some Makefile (or similar) to produce the output in the PATH_FOR_THIRD_PARTY from your hidden files.

If you chose the right layout for your repository can just use a PUBLIC_FILES directory, to checkout all PUBLIC_FILES to `PATH_FOR_THIRD_PARTY/PUBLIC_FILES`.

Note that with this method the directory layout will be the same in the publishing directory and in your repository.

BTW.: If a third-party developer changes a PUBLIC_FILE in their directory, you can simply

```
git --work-tree PATH_FOR_THIRD_PARTY add -u
```

I use this method often to publish files from a git repository. You can simply

```
git config -g alias.public '!git --work-tree $(git config --get public.root) '
git config public.root 'PATH_FOR_THIRD_PARTY'
```

so you can say

```
git public diff --name-only
```

or

```
git public status -s -uno
```

I think this method is known as or similar to a detached work-tree.

If you use this method you need to checkout the files in your local repository after you did a public commit:

```
git public add -u; git public commit -m "John Doe changed something"
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

The last line updates you local work tree to align with the commit you did above.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for my little needs. Its the whole story to use CI tools and I'm not sure yet if I need it and if I have to pay for it. But this is something interesting. I already use a pre-commit hook. But I didn't think of it in this context.

Comment: Actually I don't think that CI tools do much more than hide similar steps in a cool user interface. I never needed them yet as I'm fully happy with git alone. BTW. some thousand linux kernel developers used git alone for some years now to continuously integrate there work in the monster called the linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The feature I think you need is git rebase with interactive option -i (git rebase -i). See details from the link:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

This will create new base that you can give access a third party. I'm not an expert with rebase feature. Please review the link for more details.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I do know how git works and about the .git folder. But I want to automate it. I do have a separate project for sensitive data. I must have mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be locked into a particular service this is what you can do:

- write a script which does what you need to provide an archive of the source code, compiled binaries and other resources (if any)
- you should be able to execute this script on your own machine, for easy testing / changes
- then write another script to create a package of these the way you want to (create a ZIP file for example) and to distribute it to an FTP server, Amazon S3 or any other service you like
- now you should have everything to automate this for you. You should be able to do this on your own machine
- if you want to automate the whole process so that it's executed every time the code is changed then with this setup you can choose pretty much any Continuous Integration/Delivery service to run it for you, triggered by a Bitbucket webhook.

If you go with this setup you can use our service (https://bitrise.io/ - I'm the CTO) as it has Bitbucket webhook support built in, even for a free account, but of course you can choose any other CI/CD service as this setup doesn't require anything more than Bitbucket hook support and the ability to run your script.